# Will Modifying Product Attribute Set Cause An Error

Tags: attribute-set

We are sending products with api and also we are updating them with it. We had override _prepareDataForSave method for this reason. We are changing attribute_set in method. Is there a possibility to raise an error or break something?

Comment: What error are you getting? How did you change the code?

Comment: there is not an error. i wonder that will it causes an error ?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the attribute set will not directly give you an error, this will even be possible in Magento2 by default. The only problem I see with changing the attribute set in Magento 1.x is that there will stay data in the database for attributes that are no longer used in the new attribute-set. You will also neesdto update the product with the new attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand very well your question, but I think that [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9502311/1498857) what are you talking about ([here another solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1427/4150) from Magento StackExchange).

The problem with Magento API in WS-I Compliance is that the method `_prepareDataForSave` is missing a third 'if-condition' for the data passed: the original function only check if the `$productData->additional_attributes` is `single_data` or `multi_data` type and those are all the possible case when WS-I Compliance is not set.

With WS-I, the `$productData->additional_attributes` is not neither `single_data` or `multi_data` so we must add a third option just after the initial function as described in the other stackoverflow answer.