# Magento 1.9.0.1 SOAP import products with additional_attributes

Tags: product, import, soap, ce-1.9.0.1

I'm busy to make an import script that can import over 11.000 products from one feed with SOAP V2

Now i already made the import for the category's and subcategory's working like a charm with SOAP

After that i had made a part to add simple products into the shop what's working fine. The products are getting imported, so thats ok, but...

After that i need to import 15 additional_attributes that i already have made in the backoffice as attrubute and putted them in a map Extra.

Now i'm trying to expand my script to add the additional_attributes, but everything what i'm trying is not working. Every tip on the internet i have tryed didn;t worked out.

For the rest is the information verry poor on the website of Magento self how to make the correct array for the additional_attributes.

I have tryed about 6 different arrays to make this work, all the arrays were standing in the internet, but nothing is working. I'm now working about 20 hours on this and its nerving me out!

Is there a genious person that can help me through this problem? Or someone whants to share the golden tip how to do this...

```
$result = $client->catalogProductCreate($session, 'simple', $attribute_set_id, $artnr, array(
        'categories' => array($aProdCatId['entity_id']),
        'websites' => array(1),
        'name' => $titel,
        'description' => $descr,
        'short_description' => $descr,
        'weight' => $weight,
        'status' => '1',
        'url_key' => $title,
        'url_path' => $title,
        'visibility' => '4',
        'price' => $adviceprice,
        'tax_class_id' => 1,
        'meta_title' => $title,
        'meta_keyword' => $title,
        'meta_description' => $title,
        'additional_attributes' => array(array('power' => $power))
    ));
```

Comment: Tested with array

array('key' => 'merk', 'value' => (string)$merk) // Product imported YES | Attributes imported NO

Comment: Tested with array array(array('key' => 'merk', 'value' => (string)$merk))  // Product imported YES | Attributes imported NO

Comment: Tested with array array(array('merk' => (string)$merk)) // Product imported YES | Attributes imported NO

Comment: Tested with array array('merk' => (string)$merk) // Product imported YES | Attributes imported NO

Comment: Tested with array array('multi_data' =>  array('key' =>'merk', 'value' => (string)$merk)) // Error Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Cannot access empty property in

Comment: Tested with array array('single_data' => array('key' =>'merk', 'value' => (string)$merk)) // Error Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Cannot access empty property in

Comment: Do you use SOAP V2 with WS-I? If so, check out my question + answer on this from some time ago where I ran into the same problem: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/1308/231

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to send the `additional_attributes` as an array of arrays. And each second level array must contain a `key` and `value` property.
Something like this:

```
'additional_attributes' => array(
    array('key'=>'power', 'value'=>$power),
    array('key'=>'other_attribute', 'value'=>$otherAttributeValue),
)
```

**[EDIT]**
Looking through the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2::_prepareDataForSave` method I found this:

```
   if (property_exists($productData, 'additional_attributes')) {
        if (property_exists($productData->additional_attributes, 'single_data')) {
            foreach ($productData->additional_attributes->single_data as $_attribute) {
                $_attrCode = $_attribute->key;
                $productData->$_attrCode = $_attribute->value;
            }
        }
        if (property_exists($productData->additional_attributes, 'multi_data')) {
            foreach ($productData->additional_attributes->multi_data as $_attribute) {
                $_attrCode = $_attribute->key;
                $productData->$_attrCode = $_attribute->value;
            }
        }
        unset($productData->additional_attributes);
    }
```

I conclude from this that you need an other level in the array I mentioned above.
So try it like this:

```
'additional_attributes' => array(
    'single_data' =>  array('key'=>'power', 'value'=>$power),
)
```

or

```
'additional_attributes' => array(
    'multi_data' =>  array('key'=>'power', 'value'=>$power),
)
```

Try this new approach.

Comment: Hi Marius,

Thanks for the fast reply

I have tested this yesterday for sure i did it again, but no success the product has been imported without erros and the extra attributes

Comment: I have tested a few arrays now without any success, you can see the arrays that i have tested as a commenth in my post

Comment: @MartinMeijer. I found something else. I edited the answer. Give that a try.

Comment: i tryed both ways but i'm getting the same error on this (also tryed this yesterday, it's something like a pane in the ass to get this)

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Cannot access empty property in xxx/importSimpleProduct.php:81 Stack trace: #0 xxx/importSimpleProduct.php(81): SoapClient->__call('catalogProductC...', Array) #1 xxx/importSimpleProduct.php(81): SoapClient->catalogProductCreate('edbe4882d120908...', 'simple', 11, Object(SimpleXMLElement), Array) #2 xxx/import.php(97): include('/home/account/d...') #3 {main}

Comment: In meanwhile i've discoverd that the array is reaching the right part of the script. The array is invalid i made a testscript with the same array and how the array gets appart in the magento script.

If i test this, i'm getting a simular PHP error! This makes sense... now the solution!

<?php
$productData    = array('additional_attributes' =>  array('key' => 'foo', 'value' => "bar"));

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($productData);
echo "</pre>";

foreach ($productData->additional_attributes->multi_data as $_attribute) {
    echo $_attribute->key."<br />";
    echo $_attribute->value."<br />";
}
?>

Comment: I puted (object) in front of the array... now the error diapears now ;) so i assume he is still unsetting the array

Still it's not adding the extra attributes... i wil keep on testing!